# difference between return and dispatch in actions: Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have noticed that sometimes actions in Redux use `return` and others `dispatch`. I also noticed that `dispatch` is used when there is some async operation in that action function, like reading/posting from/to a database, but I don't understand why. Could anyone shed some light on the crucial difference. Why don't we use `dispatch` all the time for example, as in context API in React?

EDIT: I will add an example, that doesn't deal with the backend, so there is no `async` `await` cycle:

```
 //with return
    export const addLog = (log) => {
       return{
         type: ADD_LOG,
         payload: log
       }
    }
    //with dispatch
    export const addLog = (log) => disptach => {
       dispatch{
         type: ADD_LOG,
         payload: log
       }
    }
```

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

I am quite surprised nobody has come up with a definite answer. This comes really late but I will post this for people having the same question using redux-thunk as an example.
As per the [docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions):

*there is just one important thing you need to know: by using this specific middleware, an action creator can return a function instead of an action object. This way, the action creator becomes a thunk*

The function returned receives the dispatch method as an argument, which you should use to trigger state updates, **since the function by itself cannot dispatch actions** event if you return an object. For example:

```
const getEvents = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await fetch(
        'https://someendpoint/events'
    );
    const events = await res.json();

    return { // <-- this will NOT be sent to any reducer
        type: GET_EVENTS,
        events: [],
    };

   dispatch({ // <-- this will 
        type: GET_EVENTS,
        events,
    });
 };
```

};

The [section](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators) on Async Action creators explains this in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

`dispatch` is a function of the Redux store. You call store.dispatch to dispatch an action. **This is the only way to trigger a state change.**

For more details, please refer to https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: But both return and dispatch can trigger state change.

Comment: I added an example in my question.